# SSIS 2012 in Visual Studio throws error "insufficient memory"

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

When I try to run any SSIS 2012 packages in Visual Studio, it throws the error shown below; all the packages were running fine before, but none is running now:

> Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program. (Microsoft Visual Studio)
>
> Program Location:
>
> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
>   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
>   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Interop.NativeMethods.ThrowOnFailure(Int32 hr, Int32[] expectedHRFailure)
>   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Shell.DataWarehouseOutputWindowFactory.CreateOutputWindow(Guid windowGuid, String windowCaption)
>   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Shell.DataWarehouseOutputWindowFactory.GetStandardOutputWindow(StandardOutputWindow standardOutputWindow)
>   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DtsPackagesFolderProjectFeature.ExecuteTaskOrPackage(ProjectItem prjItem, String taskPath)

Can someone help?

Comment: I also noticed the 'Debug' tab has disappeared from the Visual Studio project.

Comment: If this is taking place only on your computer and not on any others, then try restarting the WMI Service on your computer.  I'm thinking the last few errors listed are due to the first pertaining to the InteropServices.

Comment: The SQL server instance is on a stand alone server and I am the admin.

Comment: Issue is resolved, we have reinstalled service pack 1, then restarted the server and all worked.